# Kali Linux hotspot settings

Tags: linux, kali-linux, settings, wifi-hotspot

I am running Kali Linux Rolling and I have found out that I am able to turn my machine into a hot spot when I plug in my ethernet cable and go to network settings etc. When I turn on the hot spot everything works fine, but I can't find any setting to change the ssid or the password of the hot spot. Can someone please help me out with how to change the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line

```
nmtui
```

To navigate, use the arrow keys or press Tab to step forwards and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to step back through the options. Press Enter to select an option. The Space bar toggles the status of a check box.

Select your hotspot

Hit enter and edit your connexion